# Hide the other images on hover of one image using css

Tags: html, css

I have code like this

```
<tr>
<td>
    <img id="one" src="abc.jpg">
</td>
<td>
    <img id="two" src="xyz.jpg">
</td>
<td>
    <img id="three" src="def.jpg">
</td>
</tr>
```

Initially I want to display all the three images
But when I hover on image one  image two and three should be hidden

how to do that?

Comment: Do you want to use JavaScript?  Have you tried using JavaScript?

Comment: What research have you done so far? What has worked and what hasn't? Can you post some of the css and/or js you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Give your `<tr>` a class.  Then hide the images when the row is hovered, but show the image that is being hovered:

```
.imgRow:hover img {
    opacity: 0;
}
.imgRow:hover img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[jsfiddle.net/J7wHq](http://jsfiddle.net/J7wHq/)

Demo with a nice transition effect and some old IE support: [jsfiddle.net/J7wHq/2](http://jsfiddle.net/J7wHq/2/)

Answer (score 0):

It is my understand that what you are trying to do is not possible with just CSS

http://jsfiddle.net/87zh6/

```
#id1:hover + #id2
{
    //Whatever you put here will modify #id2 when #id1 is hovered.
}
```

However you can only modify the element directly following #id1. If #id2 is not the next element in code it will not work.

This is why in the jsfiddle i provided it will hide the second image but not the third.

I would suggest using a form of Javascript to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this isn't possible with just CSS. I recommend using jQuery. It is super easy to learn and it will really make your life easier. I suggest using the [W3 Tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/jQuery/).

As for your problem, you'll need to give id's to each `<td>` element and use jQuery's `.hover()` method:

```
$("#one").hover(function() {
    $("#two, #three").toggle();
});
```

That will hide/show images two and three when you move the mouse over image one. If you want to just hide the images (and not toggle) you can use:

```
$("#two, #three").hide();
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7gUL4/

Answer (score 0):

Yes use jquery:

```
<script src=" <!-- you can put jqueries code URL in hear go to code.jquery.com copy paste url --> ">
</script> <!-- that loads jquery's stuff -->

<script>
$("#one").hover(function(){
       $("img').hide();
});
 <!-- repeat for others -->
</script>
```